# How to update a document after creating one in mongodb nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

Hey I am having problem trying to update a document in mongoDB after creating one. So I am trying write RestAPI flashcard system and there is a FlashcardDeckCollection collection which basically just collects all the decks of the user. What I am trying to achieve is to create a deck and afterwards update the other document with the ID number of the deck.

This is my code so far:

```
exports.newset = (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        const error = new Error("Validation Failed.");
        error.statusCode = 422;
        error.data = errors.array();
        throw error;
    }
    const title = req.body.title;

    const deck = new flashcardDeck({
        collectionId: req.collectionId,
        setTitle: title,
        flashcards: []
    });
    deck.save().then(deck => {
        flashcardCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: deck.collectionId }, { $push: { decks: deck._id } });
    }).catch(err => handleError(err));

    return res.status(201).json({ message: `Deck Successfully created`, deckID: deck._id });
}
```

I have tried to put it inside the .then() after I save the creation of a new document, but sadly that does not work.

Comment: What 'does not work's about it? Are you getting an error or something else? What is the response from the database for the `findOneAndUpdate()` operation?

Comment: It does not update anything in the database. Nothing throws an error when I send API request with postman.